# Xvfb: connection refused when running test script via browser on Fedora

Tags: fedora, xvfb, selenium

I have a python script which will only be triggered by calling `my.ip.address/test`. It works fine if I run the PHP code via command line.

However,if I access the test automation via browser using the url specified, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "scripts/crawler.py",
line 10, in driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities={"marionette":True}) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
line 152, in __init__ keep_alive=True) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
line 98, in __init__ self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
line 188, in start_session response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
line 252, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",    
line 194, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

Error in geckodriver.log:

```
1495299180874   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /usr/lib/firefox/firefox with args ["-marionette"]
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :99
```

Simple Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver   
import time
import sys

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities={"marionette":True})

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800,600))
display.start()

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
print driver.title
driver.close()
display.stop()
```

PHP code snippet for `/test` endpoint:

```
$cmd = 'xvfb-run -a python scripts/crawler.py'
return shell_exec($cmd);
```

Already installed `Xvfb` and run it:

```
$ whoami
  codekaizer #with root privileges
$ Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -ac -fbdir /tmp/.X11-unix/X99 &
```

I've verified that `/tmp/.X11-unix/X99` socket is listening to the `Xvfb` process.

I'm quite stuck right now and really appreciate someone's help!

Details:

- Firefox 53.0
- Geckodriver 0.16.1
- Fedora 22 x86_64

Thanks!
- ck